JQuery - ajax sending array to Spring controller - bad request
I am using Spring 5.3.9, jackson-core and jackson-databind- 2.17.1 version. From UI, I am sending json array to the controller. I have tried multiple parameters types in the controller and none of them are working. Getting bad request.

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/secure")
 public class PrsPyamentUtilizationSave {

@PostMapping(value = "/prsPyamentUtilSave.html", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String prsPaymentUtilValidation(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> [] list) {
    
     System.out.println("paymentUtils: " + paymentUtils);
    

     return "OK";
}


}

if I change it to String it is working but output doesn't seems like a json.
public String prsPaymentUtilValidation(@RequestBody String paymentUtils) 
  {
    
     System.out.println("jsonArray: " + paymentUtils);
return "OK";
 }


jsonArray: list%5B0%5D%5BReportId%5D=1234&list%5B0%5D%5BProviderId%5D=204437&list%5B0%5D%5BProgramTypeId%5D=1&list%5B0%5D%5BFcpUnits%5D=6&list%5B1%5D%5BReportId%5D=1234&list%5B1%5D%5BProviderId%5D=99999&list%5B1%5D%5BProgramTypeId%5D=1&list%5B1%5D%5BFcpUnits%5D=7

Changed to RestController as suggested.
    @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/secure")
public class PrsPyamentUtilizationSave {

    @PostMapping(value = "/prsPyamentUtilSave.html")    
    public String prsPyamentUtilSave(@RequestBody List<PaymentDTO> paymenDTOs) {        
         System.out.println("jsonArray: " + paymenDTOs); 
         return "OK";
    }
}


I just need to receive a valid json in controller.

Yes, a String will always work because it's just that, a String.  Your Map won't work because your data isn't structured as a Map.  Consider making a DTO for this.
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class PaymentDTO {

    @JsonProperty("ReportId")
    private String reportId;

    @JsonProperty("ProviderId")
    private long providerId;

    @JsonProperty("ProgramTypeId")
    private long programTypeId;

    @JsonProperty("FcpUnits")
    private String fcpUnits;
}

Then you just need to make your controller take a List of these.
public String prsPaymentUtilValidation(@RequestBody List<PaymentDTO> paymenDTOs) {


Hi Lane, Now I am getting bad request again.

@user3067524 There's other stuff I see here that's worrisome.  Does this controller render views or data?  If the latter, then consider using @RestController instead of @Controller.  Also, drop the produces, Spring will figure this out based on what you are returning.  You can also drop the @ResponseBody annotation

I have updated it as RestController. Still getting bad data error.  Can you please take a look at Ajax call ?

Forget the AJAX part and just get your API working first, otherwise you'll be battling multiple issues.  Use postman or curl to test that your API works, then tackle the AJAX part.  You haven't really provided enough details to make any decisions on the client side anyway.

I have tried sending an json array of objects from postman and RestConreoller works perfect but I don't understand why ajx posting as "list%5B0%5D%5BReportId%5D=1234&list%5B0%5D%5BProviderId%5D=204437&list%5B0%5D%5BProgramTypeId%5D=1&list%5B0%5D%5BFcpUnits%5D=6&list%5B1%5D%5BReportId%5D=1234&list%5B1%5D%5BProviderId%5D=99999&list%5B1%5D%5BProgramTypeId%5D=1&list%5B1%5D%5BFcpUnits%5D=7". I think we need to fix the ajax call.

I have fixed the issue. Thank you so much for putting me in right direction. I will post the answer.

Updated the Ajax call by removing the key "list" and adding the "JSON.stringify" to the array object.
$.post(/prsPyamentUtilSave.html', JSON.stringify(list), function (data) { result = data; });

Also used RestController as suggested by Lane. Thanks Lane!!
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/secure") public class PrsPyamentUtilizationSave {
@PostMapping(value = "/prsPyamentUtilSave.html")
  public String prsPyamentUtilSave(@RequestBody List<PaymentDTO> paymenDTOs) {               
  System.out.println("jsonArray: " + paymenDTOs);
   return "OK"; 
 } 
}

